# How to disable all Kafka related auto configuration from yaml/properties file in spring-boot-2 without removing dependencies?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have create a spring-boot-2 gradle project, also in `build.gradle` file i have added Kafka related dependency which given below.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin'
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bus-kafka'
}
```

now i want to disable all Kafka related Auto configuration from `application.yaml`
file for that i have tried given below code in my yaml file.

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
      exclude:
        - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration
```

After implementing above things still the Kafka got Auto-configured and start integration of Kafka with the application.

Also i have tried below code but this is also not working for me.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = KafkaAutoConfiguration.class)
public class ApiGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Now please can any one help me out, how can i disable all auto configuration related to kafka from yaml/properties file ?

Thanks,

Comment: For me it worked in application.yaml as you have tried.  But with spring-boot 3, didn't try with spring-boot 2 but I think it still should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = KafkaAutoConfiguration.class)`

You should do `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = KafkaAutoConfiguration.class)`

Comment: How to exclude kafkaautoconfiguration for specific profile? When spring.profile.active=QA then I want to exclude Kafka auto configuration.